# Is there a way to get the last call COST information programatically in android

Tags: android

I need to get the cost of call after the call is ended, ie, the Cost per call as subscribed with the Service Provider. Is there anyway to get this information on the device programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe there is a way to send an USSD code (e.g. `*101#`) and capture the text message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be possible.

Cost per call is dependent on the Service Provider (Carrier).
Carrier charges depends on so many factors like the plan you have selected and the like. For postpaid cards, this is even more difficult because there might be applicable discounts etc.

May be, you can consider discussing directly with the service operators and ask for their APIs (IF any) and calculate the last call cost.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is possible.Theres no way for your app to get the values unless you provide them.